# How to avoid that overflow-x affects the y axis?

Tags: html, css

I am aware that similar questions have been asked but so far none of them was able to help me, so here it goes. I have a table whose container has fixed width so it overflows on the x axis when it has too many columns.

This table also has header filters, and the problem shows itself when I have dropdown filter with too few rows on the table. If the height of the dropdown is bigger then the height of the table it will add scroll-y even though I only have set the overflow-x. Here's some mock code:

```css
.list-container {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.list-row {
  height: 50px;
}

.list-header-filters {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 600px;
}

.down {
  background-color: lime;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <div class="list-header-filters">
    <div class="down"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-row"></div>
  <div class="list-row"></div>
  <div class="list-row"></div>
</div>
```

If you run this code you will see a pink container with a wide of orange div that I want to be contained in the container width overflow-x: auto but the tall green div I want to go out of the container without creating a vertical scrollbar. I have played around with position absolute but this is not pratical since I can have multiple dropdowns and I cannot possible give coordinates to all of them. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `z-index` and `overflow-y: hidden;` to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, `z-index` doesn't do anything at all and `overflow-y: hidden` just hides the part of the dropdown that overflows (that is actually expected of the `overflow-y: hidden`).